# $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\lambda x^2} x^l e^{-x^2}\, dx \sim \lambda^{-(l+1)/2} \sum_{j=0}^\infty c_j^{(l)} \lambda^{-j}$ for even $l\in \mathbb N$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, harmonic-analysis, oscillatory-integral

We aim to show $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\lambda x^2} x^l e^{-x^2}\, dx \sim \lambda^{-(l+1)/2} \sum_{j=0}^\infty c_j^{(l)} \lambda^{-j} \tag{9}$$ for even non-negative integers $l$, as done in Chapter 8 of Stein's *Harmonic Analysis: Real-Variable Methods, Orthogonality, and Oscillatory Integrals*. I shall ask two questions, while quoting the proof in the text.

> The left side of $(9)$ is $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(1-i\lambda) x^2} x^l \, dx;$$
> setting $z = (1-i\lambda)^{1/2}\, x$ and noting that the rapid decay of $e^{-z^2}$ allows us to replace the contour $(1-i\lambda)^{1/2}\cdot \Bbb R$ by $\Bbb R$, we see that the above integral equals $$(1-i\lambda)^{-1/2 - l/2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} x^l \, dx$$

1. What role does the rapid decay of $e^{-z^2}$ play in replacing the contour $(1-i\lambda)^{1/2}\cdot \Bbb R$ by $\Bbb R$? I'm not sure how to show that $$\int_{(1-i\lambda)^{1/2}\cdot \Bbb R} e^{-x^2} x^l \, dx = \int_{\Bbb R} e^{-x^2} x^l \, dx$$

> Here, we have fixed the principal branch of $z^{-(l+1)/2}$ in the complex plane slit along the negative half-axis. With this determination, we have $$(1-i\lambda)^{-(l+1)/2} = \lambda^{-(l+1)/2} \cdot (\lambda^{-1} - i)^{-(l+1)/2} $$ if $\lambda > 0$. Thus, the power series expansion of $(w-i)^{-(l+1)/2}$ (on the open unit disc) gives us the asymptotic expansion $(9)$ with $w = \lambda^{-1} \to 0$.

2. What *exactly* does the author mean by the symbol $\sim$ in this context? Following the above argument, we would get $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\lambda x^2} x^l e^{-x^2}\, dx = \lambda^{-(l+1)/2} \sum_{j=0}^\infty c_j^{(l)} \lambda^{-j}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} x^l \, dx\right) \tag{$\ast$}$$
   and I wonder why the term $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} x^l \, dx$ is dropped from the expression, even though it is *dependent* on $l$.

Comment: $\sim$ means an [asymptotic expansion](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.1#iii). The method leading to the expansion is called the [method of stationary phase](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3#iv). In this special case, with the change of variables $t=x^2$ a [simpler result](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3.E5) is used. You have to compute the $l$-integrals and re-define $c_j^{(l)}$ accordingly.

Comment: The contour replacement is done by rotating back the path of integration to $\mathbb R$. This can be done using Cauchy's theorem and the fact that the integrand vanishes on the arc at infinity.

Comment: @Gary Thanks, I understand $(2)$ now. The given expansion is asymptotic, in the sense that it works for $\lambda\to\infty$, and also the constants $c_j^{(l)}$ already include the integral dependent on $l$. However, could you provide more details for $(1)$, perhaps in an answer?

Comment: I see that this case is even simpler and we actually have a series that converges for $\lambda>1$. No need for stat. phase. You can show the equality of the two integrals as follows: take the difference of them, join the "endpoints" at $\pm\infty$ by two arcs (along those arcs the integral vanishes due to the decay of the integrand, so in principle nothing has changed). Then you have the integral of a holomorphic function along two infinite, closed contours. Both are zero due to Cauchy's theorem. Since the arcs at infinity do not contribute, we see that the difference of the integrals is zero.